# Preventing ground spikes while operating a solid state Tesla coil

Tags: tesla-coil

With a Tesla coil being a high-frequency, high voltage device, and the secondary coil connected to ground, is there a way to prevent the high frequency signal from interfering with other electrical devices when connected to mains ground, such as some sort of low pass filter? I know I can simply avoid this by connecting it directly to the earth or some sort of piping that connects to ground, I am just wondering if there is an alterantive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: More than likely, the EMI from the massive display of highly mobile electrons IS the main source of interference rather than ground but, if you can justify otherwise please go ahead.

Comment: Well yes that would be the case, but I believe only localised, but when connected to mains ground, it is feeding back into the household circuitry and it can be possibly that any other grounded electronics could be affected, as I read in a few places , for example here: http://www.instructables.com/answers/How-do-you-ground-a-Tesla-coil/

Comment: I think not i.e. I disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Tesla coil is going to make a lot of RF.  That's its job.  How you ground one end of the output doesn't change this.  At best it moves around where exactly this RF noise will be seen.

If you ground one side of the output to the ground in a wall plug, then the high frequency current runs along the ground wire, eventually to the earth ground somewhere near the breaker panel.  That ground wire has nicely low resistance to the 50 or 60 Hz power, but very little consideration went into making it low impedance at RF frequencies.  There can therefore be a substantial voltage across this ground wire between where you connect the Tesla coil and earth ground.  That can cause equipment plugged into anyplace where the ground has significant RF on it to misbehave.

No, there isn't some magic way to "filter" the current thru the ground to somehow put less nasty RF current thru it.  Whatever you use as the ground connection to the Tesla coil will carry nasty RF currents.  If you don't want those nasty currents on your AC ground wire, then you can't use it to ground your Tesla coil.

Connecting the Tesla coil directly to earth ground via its own ground connection moves the RF power that kept a large signal across the ground wire to someplace else.  That is probably better for the equipment plugged into the AC outlets, but may be worse for other things.  In the end, emitting 10s of Watts of RF power is very likely going to cause trouble somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a magic way to filter out the RF from ground connection.  Don't connect it to mains ground.  Think like this:

What if your TC was sitting on an infinite horizontal conductor-sheet?  In that case any connection between Earth and the *other side* of the sheet (the bottom,) will have zero current.  An infinite "ground plane" is like a faraday cage.  The strong e-fields are all on one side of the groundplane conductor, with all the high rf currents trapped in that conductor plane.  The TC still works fine even if the conductor-plane isn't connected to the Earth.

So, make the ground-sheet be non-infinite.

Get a 1ft vertical Tesla coil, and place a 3ft aluminum plate on the table below it, with the TC's ground wire connected to the center of the plate.  Then most of the flux-lines of e-field coming from the top of the TC will land on the aluminum plate.  If we also connected the plate to Earth, this earth-wire will only have very small RF current, at least when compared to the huge current in the coil's base wire.

Don't forget that Tesla Coils are VLF, and way too small to act as good antennas.  Most of the nasty strong EM will remain local.  A Tesla coil is like a capacitor, with the coil-top as one plate  ...so where is the second plate?  Under your feet?!!  To limit the fields, don't use the dirt or the metal conduit in the walls, but instead provide a large ground surface right at the bottom of the coil.

A Tesla Coil is like a ham vertical, a quarter-wave groundplane antenna.  If we unwisely remove the antenna's groundplane, then the full RF current goes into your house wiring.  Scrambles digital clocks, gives small rf burns to anyone running their fingertips across your fridge.

Vertical Tesla coils are still dipoles.  All Tesla coils really should have some sort of metal ground-plane at their base, or at least a bunch of horizontal wires connected to the base wire and arranged radially.  The radial wires should be as long as the TC height (or ideally, much longer.)  Or, the base of small TC could be placed on a metal table and "grounded" to a screw in the table center, with no other earth connection.  The major RF will then be in the table surface, and it behaves as a partial faraday cage (a non-infinite ground plane.)

And, for large TCs, if creating a metal ground-plane using radial cables laid on the floor around the coil, that will move the few-hundred-amperes of RF into these cables, so it doesn't end up creating standing-waves in AC green-ground, frying appliances or setting fire to any loose connections somewhere within the walls.