# Why are sparks coming out of the bottom of my Tesla coil secondary?

Tags: high-voltage, tesla-coil

I built a very basic tesla coil and I'm getting sparks out of the secondary bottom instead of the breakout point in the top.
The bottom of the secondary is not connected to anything. The top is connected to the coil toroid and a breakout point.
How do I get sparks to get out of the top breakout point?

The coil:
[image: coil]

Bottom of secondary:
[image: bottom of secondary]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom of the secondary should be connected to some sort of ground connection.

If you are operating indoors, then a large sheet of foil underneath the secondary is ideal. I notice you have a wire mesh cage around your electronics in the base. This could possibly do as an alternative to a metal sheet, if all pieces of it are connected together, but increasing its size with a sheet of foil underneath, connected to it, would be even better. The foil, or your mesh cage, must also be connected to the safety/earth ground of your mains supply at the point where it powers the coil.

Put a mains filter at the coil inlet. If you don't have a mains filter, use X2 type capacitors to RF-short both live and neutral conductors to safety ground. This keeps RF interference from conducting back into the electrical network differentially between conductors.

If you are operating outdoors, then a spike into the ground is fine.

Comment: That mesh looks kind of like plastic to me.

Comment: Are you sure it is safe to connect the mains ground to the sheet? Won't the coil send spikes through the mains ground and possibly damage all the electrical equipment connected to the mains network?

Comment: It's unsafe not to. It's safer yet to use a mains filter at that point that has capacitors to RF-short all the three mains lead conductors together.

Comment: @Kopharex are you familiar with the concept of 'grasping the nettle'. It's about taking control of the mains connection. It *is* there, it *is* coupled to the electric field from the TC, and sometimes it *will* get hit by arcs. Connecting it to the secondary bottom and using X2 caps or a filter to RF short all the conductors together at the point of entry to the TC is about defining the relationship of the mains connection to the coil, rather than leaving it to chance.

Comment: I see. So ground would be connected to the ground plane via some sort of filter. What kind of filter? What are X2 capacitors? Excuse my ignorance, it's the first time I work with mains on a complex project.

Comment: @Kopharex No, coil ground would be connected to mains/safety ground directly, the filter is a way of getting mains-rated capacitors to connect live, neutral and ground at RF. An X2 capacitor is rated to withstand the 1500V spikes that mains throws at components, and fail safe if it can't. Needless to say, a mains filter is rated for that.

Comment: @Kopharex perhaps to be clearer, the live and neutral connections to the TC electronics are filtered, the ground connection from mains/safety ground to TC common ground goes via the ground terminal on the mains filter. The secondary bottom, the sheet, the mesh, should all be connected to the TC common ground. If you don't have a purchased mains filter, then connect X2 caps from the TC common ground to the live and neutral terminals at the TC electronics.

Comment: @Neil_UK Okay, I'm unsure about one thing: is it safe to use the ground from the filter for the bottom of the tesla coil? Will it work despite the kilo-volts of the coil? I can't help but be a bit worried. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Kopharex to reiterate, it's not safe not to. But it's not sufficient by itself. Think of the electrical circuit which comprises the secondary, and the capacitance between the topload and 'all things groundy', that's where the RF current flows. If you're indoors, the 'groundy' things include wiring in the walls and ceiling, plumbing pipes, which is why you should (a) have a decent size foil sheet under, connected to ground and (b) connect the ground wire at the TC supply, to control where the RF current flows, and to minimise voltage drops. Otherwise, what voltages do you get where? who knows!

Comment: @Neil_UK I understand what you mean about knowing where the RF current flows. It's just that I read quite often that it is not safe to connect a tesla coil to mains ground as it could fry other electronic equipment on the same network. That's what i'm worried about because I have to bring this trap to school. Thank you again :)

Comment: @Neil_UK Here for example it is recommended not to connect a tesla coil to mains ground: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281442/preventing-ground-spikes-while-operating-a-solid-state-tesla-coil

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your problem is that your secundairy coil is does not have a connection to ground as it should. The primairy setup in your case can look somewhat different but a tesla transformer works always the same.

Comment: Thank you. If i cannot drive a rod in the ground can I use an aluminium foil plane as ground?

Comment: The current in the secondairy circuit is very small. A short rod into the ground is enough. A free floating aluminium foil plane free on an isolated surface is not good.

Comment: So there is no hope for using this coil indoors?

Comment: Make sure you work safe. Make a proper earth and run a wire to the basis of the coil. There are more ways to obtain a ground but i do not want to suggest them because i do not know your situation. Remember you are working with very high voltages. So dont forget Murphy

Comment: your windings on the secondary seem close together.

Comment: @Jasen the windings on the secondary look right to me, for a Tesla coil!

Comment: I heard somewhere that the optimum was to space them apart by about 1 wire diameter.

Comment: @Jasen Touching turns is optimum, as borne out by all successful coils you see pictured. If voltage breakdown between turns was a problem, then spacing would improve things, but it's not a problem even with touching turns. If self capacitance was a problem, then spacing turns would reduce it slightly, but it's just fine with touching turns. RF resistance *is* a problem, and that demands wire with the largest surface area possible, given the constraints of secondary size and number of turns.

Comment: spacing the turns apart dramatically reduces the stress on the insulation (good).  and also reduces the coils inter-winding capacitance, (increasing the resonant frequency), as a thinner wire is needed for the same number of turns it also increases the coils resistance (bad).  if your secondary isn't producing megavolts spacing probably isn't required.